# Как объяснить результаты измерения времени выполнения программы ?

Tags: windows, gcc, производительность, virtualbox, linux

Программа на C. Не могу понять, как интерпретировать результаты измерения работы локальной и внешней функции, т.е. когда ее код написан в том же файле, откуда она вызывается и в отдельном файле.

Компьютер CPU i5-2500 3.30 GHz  Windows 7. На ней стоит VirtualBox 4.1.6 c Ubuntu 10.04.

Измеряется время вызова функции, которая много раз в цикле реверсирует переданный ей массив, размещаемый в куче вызывающей программой. Один раз меряем локальный вызов, а во втором случае вызов той же функции (с другим именем), определенной в своем файле.

Windows

```
c:/Users/avp/src/sort $ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

c:/Users/avp/src/sort $ gcc -O3 t.c e.c
c:/Users/avp/src/sort $ ./a 1000000
test 1000000 elements 1000 loops
internal 8057 msec
external 8456 msec
c:/Users/avp/src/sort $ gcc t.c e.c
c:/Users/avp/src/sort $ ./a 1000000
test 1000000 elements 1000 loops
internal 10832 msec
external 10518 msec
c:/Users/avp/src/sort $
```

Linux

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ gcc --version
gcc.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ gcc -O3 t.c e.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ ./a.out 1000000
test 1000000 elements 1000 loops
internal 637 msec
external 7035 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ gcc t.c e.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$ ./a.out 1000000
test 1000000 elements 1000 loops
internal 8153 msec
external 8144 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst/sort$
```

Заранее извиняюсь за объем, но привожу код.

t.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

static long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}

static void
swap (void *t, void *a, void *b, int size)
{
  memcpy(t,a,size);
  memcpy(a,b,size);
  memcpy(b,t,size);
}

void
rev (void *a, void *t, int n, int l, int size)
{
  while (l--) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < j; i++,j--) 
      swap(t, a+i*size,a+j*size,size);
  }
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = 100000, l = 1000;
  if (ac > 1)
    if ((n = atoi(av[1])) < 3)
      n = 100000;
  if (ac > 2)
    if ((l = atoi(av[2])) < 1)
      l = 100;

  printf ("test %d elements %d loops\n",n,l);
  long long start;
  int  tt;
  int *a = malloc(n*sizeof(*a));
  void *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*a));
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = rand();

  start = mtime();
  rev(a,tmp,n,l,sizeof(*a));
  tt = mtime()-start;
  printf ("internal %d msec\n",tt);

  start = mtime();
  erev(a,tmp,n,l,sizeof(*a));
  tt = mtime()-start;
  printf ("external %d msec\n",tt);

  exit (0);
}
```

e.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void
swap (void *t, void *a, void *b, int size)
{
  memcpy(t,a,size);
  memcpy(a,b,size);
  memcpy(b,t,size);
}

void
erev (void *a, void *t, int n, int l, int size)
{
  while (l--) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < j; i++,j--) 
      swap(t, a+i*size,a+j*size,size);
  }
}
```

Собственно смущает разница во времени выполнения **на виртуальной машине**. Какие объяснения этому факту можно привести ? Обратите внимание, это проявляется при -O3 и версия компилятора в винде другая. Но **в чем именно** может заключаться такая фантастическая оптимизация или **почему виртуальная машина** так влияет ?

Может быть где-то в программе ошибка, а я ее не вижу ?  Но, я обратил внимание на такое поведение системы при разработке других программ, а здесь привел ярко иллюстрирующий эту аномалию (?) пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ, даже не глядя в генерируемый компилятором код. Действительно, как сказл [@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg) дело в оптимизации, но в такой уровень оптимизации я просто поверить не мог.

Дело в том, что аргумент size в функции rev() (и далее в swap()) **на самом деле константа**, известная компилятору при компиляции t.c (sizeof(int)), но неизвестная для функций в e.c.

После

```
size = sizeof(int);
```

в начале erev() все заработало одинаково.

Answer (score 3):

Ну так разные версии gcc. Современные версии вообще очень хорошо все оптимизируют. В частности, небольшие функции при -О2 и -О3 могут автоматически делаться встроенными. Возможны и другие оптимизации. Надо смотреть генерируемый ассемблеровский код.

Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с другими уровнями оптимизации.

Comment: Я бы понял про "*встроенность*" если бы цикл был в вызывающей прграмме. Тут что-то другое. Разница во времени исполнения **на порядок**.

Поставлю вопрос по другому:

 **почему вместе с main() оптимизируется, а в другом файле нет ?**

Comment: Чего спорить? Надо в ассемблер глядеть.

Comment: Да, дело в оптимизации.